# Postgresql query runs slow and fast. Explain plan shows high shared read

Tags: postgresql, explain

I have a high throughput table which gets around 20million inserts a day with N_PROCESSING_STATE = 0
A set of processes select new records from this table, group them and insert or update another table. Once done the processed records are updated with N_PROCESSING_STATE = 1
A daily housekeeping job deletes these records.

My problem is that the select sometimes runs fast, and sometimes runs very slow. I have explain plan results from running the same query multiple times over 20 minutes and need help understanding why the speed is so different

Here three examples. Run pretty much directly after the previous finished.

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..6541.54 rows=165 width=6155) (actual time=0.088..137855.110 rows=990 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=6026143 read=432018
  ->  Index Scan using ipc_message_print_proc_state on ipc_message_print  (cost=0.56..6541.54 rows=165 width=6155) (actual time=0.086..137854.983 rows=990 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (n_processing_state = 0)
        Filter: (mod((ascii(substr((c_transaction_id)::text, 1, 1)) + ascii("right"((c_transaction_id)::text, 1))), 4) = 3)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3111
        Buffers: shared hit=6026143 read=432018
Planning Time: 0.499 ms
Execution Time: 137855.332 ms

Limit  (cost=0.56..6546.66 rows=165 width=6155) (actual time=0.063..27.692 rows=3000 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=9232 read=2
  ->  Index Scan using ipc_message_print_proc_state on ipc_message_print  (cost=0.56..6546.66 rows=165 width=6155) (actual time=0.061..27.346 rows=3000 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (n_processing_state = 0)
        Filter: (mod((ascii(substr((c_transaction_id)::text, 1, 1)) + ascii("right"((c_transaction_id)::text, 1))), 4) = 3)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 8869
        Buffers: shared hit=9232 read=2
Planning Time: 0.451 ms
Execution Time: 27.992 ms

Limit  (cost=0.56..11645.97 rows=289 width=6157) (actual time=0.064..141655.565 rows=973 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=6194738 read=444040 written=938
  ->  Index Scan using ipc_message_print_proc_state on ipc_message_print  (cost=0.56..11645.97 rows=289 width=6157) (actual time=0.062..141655.472 rows=973 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (n_processing_state = 0)
        Filter: (mod((ascii(substr((c_transaction_id)::text, 1, 1)) + ascii("right"((c_transaction_id)::text, 1))), 4) = 3)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3127
        Buffers: shared hit=6194738 read=444040 written=938
Planning Time: 5.542 ms
Execution Time: 141655.720 ms
```

I can see that the "fast" one is only using the cached data.
I also see that the others are reading new entries. What I don't understand is why the huge difference.
The fast one is retrieving 3000 and as there is a limit set I assume that helps. The question is why there is why over 400'000 records need to be read for the other two queries. Why aren't they cached after the first try. There were definitely less than 200'000 new records inserted during that time.

Can I see somewhere if I need to provide more memory? (shared buffers is set to 24GB)

My actual Query

```
explain (analyze,buffers,timing) SELECT K_MESSAGE_PRINT_ID, D_PRINT_TIMESTAMP, C_MESSAGE_ID, C_TRANSACTION_ID, C_MESSAGE_PRINT_TYPE, N_MESSAGE_STATE, B_MESSAGE_ACTIVE
, FK_INFRA_OBJECT_ID, FK_FLOW_STEP_ID, FK_NEXT_FLOW_STEP_ID, FK_MESSAGE_CATEGORY, FK_ACK_USER_PROFILE_ID, FK_SERVICE_FORMAT_ID, FK_MESSAGE_PROFILE_ID
, FK_MESSAGE_TYPE_VERSION_ID, FK_MESSAGE_INSTANCE_ID, FK_WORKFLOW_ID, OS_WORKFLOW_ACTION_ID, C_REF_1, C_REF_2, C_REF_3, C_VISIBILITY_CODE
, FK_VISIBILITY_USER_PROFILE_ID, FK_VISIBILITY_GROUP_ID, FK_VISIBILITY_ORGANISATION_ID, C_TAG_INFO
, CASE WHEN CLOB_MESSAGE IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END AS HAS_CLOB_MESSAGE, CASE WHEN CLOB_PROPRIETARY_MESSAGE IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END AS HAS_PROPRIETARY_CLOB_MESSAGE
, CASE WHEN CLOB_MESSAGE_ERRORS IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END AS HAS_CLOB_MESSAGE_ERRORS, CASE WHEN CLOB_STATUS_MSG IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END AS HAS_CLOB_STATUS_MESSAGE
, C_STATUS_CODE, C_COMMENT, C_TARGET_INFO, N_PROCESSING_STATE, C_LINK_INFO, C_GATE_NAME,C_MESSAGE_SUB_STATE, C_MESSAGE_TYPE, C_MESSAGE_TYPE_2
, C_ORIGINAL_SENDER, C_FINAL_RECEIVER, C_SENDER, C_RECEIVER, C_MESSAGE_ID_2, C_MESSAGE_REF, D_VALUE_DATE, C_AMOUNT, C_AMOUNT_CURR, C_ORGANISATION
, C_ORGANISATION_2, N_AMOUNT_VALUE,C_ATT_21, C_ATT_23, C_ATT_22, C_ATT_24, C_ATT_7, C_ATT_3, C_ATT_11, C_ATT_25, C_ATT_1, C_ATT_19, C_ATT_4
, C_ATT_5, C_ATT_13, C_ATT_9, C_ATT_2, C_ATT_10, C_ATT_20, C_ATT_18, C_ATT_26, C_ATT_15, C_ATT_12, C_ATT_6, C_ATT_8, C_ATT_14, N_ATT_2, N_ATT_4
, N_ATT_13, N_ATT_14, N_ATT_1, N_ATT_6, N_ATT_12, N_ATT_3, N_ATT_11, D_ATT_3, D_ATT_1, D_ATT_2, D_ATT_4, D_ATT_5, D_ATT_6 
FROM IPC_MESSAGE_PRINT 
WHERE N_PROCESSING_STATE = 3 
AND MOD(ASCII(SUBSTR(C_TRANSACTION_ID,1,1)) + ASCII(RIGHT(C_TRANSACTION_ID, 1)),4) = 0  
limit 3000
```

I have setup vacuum analyse on this table every 15min and this has made the situation get better.
I also ran a vacuum full to verify that there is no bloat issue and that the indexes are fine.

Comment: Research how to create a index with a expression in PostgreSQL seams to be usefull where you do the mod ASCII substr stuff

Comment: Without table structures i think thats about the only advice possible..

Comment: Thanks Raymond. I'll see what I can find. Maybe add the MOD SUBSTR results to an index somehow.
Actually the index seems to be used OK and I think the problems solved with the info provided by @jjanes.
The main software concerned is not from me so I can only log change requests once I know exactly what needs to be changed. Indexes of course, I can take care of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have long-open transactions?

PostgreSQL doesn't store visibility info in the indexes.  So the queries that don't find 3000 entries have to run through the entire portion of index where n_processing_state = 0, then go to the table row, only to discover the tuples is no longer visible (it has been updated so that n_processing_state is no longer 0, or it has been deleted).  This is slow.  If it finds the tuple is no longer visible to itself or *any other existing transaction*, then it will mark it as dead in the index so the next query doesn't have to repeat this action.  However, if there is any other transaction that might possibly want to see that tuple, then it can't mark it dead in the index.  So one forgotten-about transaction can cause everyone else to keep visiting the same obsolete rows, over and over again.

> The question is why there is why over 400'000 records need to be read for the other two queries.

That is 400,000 pages, not records.  There is no indication in the EXPLAIN of how many rows were visited but found not to be visible.  Presumably, it is lot more than 400,000.

> Once done the processed records are updated with N_PROCESSING_STATE = 1 A daily housekeeping job deletes these records.

Is there a reason you can't just delete them right off the bat?  UPDATE followed by DELETE shortly later is going to create a lot more dead rows that need to be dealt with.

Comment: Thank you @jjanes I found old transactions. Actually a little more complicated. They are selects which are from one of the java processes connected to the DB. These have "idle in transaction" connections to the DB. Looks like this is blocking the Postgresql Vacuum from cleaning up enough. Restarting those processes every 1h seems to have resolved the issue.
I love your very concise description. This really makes sense now. The index basically becoming useless due to is not being able to mark outdated entries as dead.
I also found new bloat on the big table which I assume has the same cause.

Comment: The housekeeping deletes entries older than n days. The idea being that the system retains a history trace for monitoring purposes. In fact the entire software is to monitor messages being processed on steps of a micro service architecture messaging hub.
There's work in progress to change the setup to no longer require this table with all the updates as I completely agree this is not the way Postgresql should be used.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't solved the issue entirely yet. I have 4 parallel queries on this table, separated by the MOD(SUBSTR(... clause of the query.
I'm beginning to wonder if bad timing is making them all run far too slow while each one blocks the other from enabling the index to be updated while they all wait for DiskIO to get the correct data. I will have to follow this up

I found more information on killing index tuples here https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/killed-index-tuples/

Comment: OK, final comment from me on this. I resolved the issue thanks among other things to another post by the brilliant people at cybertec https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/

It turns out that any long running transaction will block vacuum from cleaning up dead tuples. Even transactions that have nothing to do with the table in question. This is what caused my confusion :) Ensuring that ALL transactions are closed regularly combined with plenty of vacuum(ing) solves this issue.